# Knex migration: Transaction query already complete

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-migration, knex.js

Using `knex` I want to add 2 additional columns to an existing table. To pre-existing records I'd like to add a value based on a calculation. Below is my migration file. It fails on the 2nd line: `Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined`.

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function(){
            ... cut to shorten question...
    })
};
```

---

**Update:** I removed the `Promise` and now have the migration code below. This still produces two errors, probably related to the `forEach` loop and that it doesn't wait for one part of the loop to finish before it goes on with the next part (but I don't know how else to do the loop):

> Unhandled rejection MigrationLocked: Migration table is already locked
>
> Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info

```
const Coupon = require('../../models/coupon');
const Plan = require('../../models/plan');

exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.table('transactions', (table) => {
      table.decimal('plan_price', 10, 2);
      table.decimal('discount', 10, 2).defaultTo(0);
    })

    .then(function(return_value){
      knex.select().from('transactions')
      .then((transactions) => {
        transactions.forEach(async function(trans){
          let original_price;
          let total_coupon_discount = 0;

          const plan = await Plan.where({id: trans.plan_id}).fetch();
          if (plan) { original_price = plan.get("price") };

          if (trans.coupon_id) {
            const coupon = await Coupon.where({id: trans.coupon_id}).fetch();
            if (coupon) {
              total_coupon_discount = coupon.get("discount_amount");
              original_price = trans.amount_ex_vat + couponAmount;
            }
          }

          const promise = await knex('transactions')
          .where('id', '=', trans.id)
          .update({
            plan_price: original_price,
            discount: total_coupon_discount
          }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error)
          }).then(function(){
            console.log('Added data to transaction record');
          })
        })
      })

      return return_value;
    })
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.table('transactions', (table) => {
    table.dropColumn('plan_price');
    table.dropColumn('discount');
  });
};
```

---

**Update2:** The suggested migration syntax in @Rich Churcher's answer made the migration work. But the error message about the MigrationLock remained. [Here](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1217) a similar issue is discussed. It is suggested to remove locks from the `migration_table` but even completely emptying that table made no difference for me.

So I added `DEBUG=knex:*` in `variables.env` as that site also suggests. When I then run the migration, I get the output below. Any idea what might be causing the error and how to solve this?

```
Using environment: development
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid1 +0ms
  knex:query select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = ? and table_schema = database() undefined +0ms
  knex:bindings [ 'migrations' ] undefined +0ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid1 +40ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid1 +2ms
  knex:query select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = ? and table_schema = database() undefined +40ms
  knex:bindings [ 'migrations_lock' ] undefined +39ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid1 +5ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid1 +2ms
  knex:query select * from `migrations_lock` undefined +9ms
  knex:bindings [] undefined +10ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid1 +22ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid1 +22ms
  knex:query select `name` from `migrations` order by `id` asc undefined +60ms
  knex:bindings [] undefined +62ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid1 +25ms
  knex:tx trx2: Starting top level transaction +0ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid1 +329ms
  knex:query BEGIN; trx2 +348ms
  knex:bindings undefined trx2 +347ms
  knex:query update `migrations_lock` set `is_locked` = ? where `is_locked` = ? trx2 +18ms
  knex:bindings [ 1, 0 ] trx2 +25ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +47ms
  knex:query select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = ? and table_schema = database() undefined +17ms
  knex:bindings [ 'migrations' ] undefined +8ms
  knex:query select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = ? and table_schema = database() trx2 +6ms
  knex:bindings [ 'migrations' ] trx2 +6ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +13ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +18ms
  knex:query select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = ? and table_schema = database() undefined +26ms
  knex:bindings [ 'migrations_lock' ] undefined +26ms
  knex:query select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = ? and table_schema = database() trx2 +2ms
  knex:bindings [ 'migrations_lock' ] trx2 +3ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +6ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +1ms
  knex:query select * from `migrations_lock` undefined +4ms
  knex:bindings [] undefined +3ms
  knex:query select * from `migrations_lock` trx2 +2ms
  knex:bindings [] trx2 +18ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +22ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +23ms
  knex:query select `name` from `migrations` order by `id` asc undefined +66ms
  knex:bindings [] undefined +51ms
  knex:query select `name` from `migrations` order by `id` asc trx2 +7ms
  knex:bindings [] trx2 +26ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +55ms
  knex:tx trx4: Starting top level transaction +193ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +3ms
  knex:query BEGIN; trx4 +27ms
  knex:bindings undefined trx4 +8ms
  knex:query select max(`batch`) as `max_batch` from `migrations` trx2 +23ms
  knex:bindings [] trx2 +43ms
  knex:query update `migrations_lock` set `is_locked` = ? where `is_locked` = ? trx4 +25ms
  knex:bindings [ 1, 0 ] trx4 +5ms
  knex:query alter table `transactions` add `plan_price` decimal(10, 2), add `discount` decimal(10, 2) default '0' trx2 +13ms
  knex:bindings [] trx2 +20ms
Can't take lock to run migrations: Migration table is already locked
If you are sure migrations are not running you can release the lock manually by deleting all the rows = require(migrations lock table: migrations_lock
  knex:query ROLLBACK trx4 +71ms
  knex:bindings undefined trx4 +64ms
  knex:tx trx4: releasing connection +136ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +180ms
Unhandled rejection MigrationLocked: Migration table is already locked
    (No stack trace)
From previous event:
    at Migrator._getLock (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\migrate\Migrator.js:328:13)
    at Migrator._runBatch (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\migrate\Migrator.js:343:12)
    at knex.transaction (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\migrate\Migrator.js:92:25)
    at init.then.then (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\transaction.js:91:24)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
From previous event:
    at Transaction._promise.Bluebird.using (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\transaction.js:77:12)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
From previous event:
    at new Transaction (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\transaction.js:57:30)
    at new Transaction_MySQL (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\transaction.js:7:1)
    at Client_MySQL.transaction (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:52:12)
    at Function.transaction (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\util\make-knex.js:40:31)
    at migrationListResolver.listAllAndCompleted.then.then (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\migrate\Migrator.js:91:28)
From previous event:
    at Migrator.latest (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\migrate\Migrator.js:72:8)
    at Command.commander.command.description.option.action (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\bin\cli.js:185:18)
    at Command.listener (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\node_modules\commander\index.js:360:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\node_modules\commander\index.js:799:12)
    at Command.parse (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\node_modules\commander\index.js:563:21)
    at Liftoff.invoke (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\knex\bin\cli.js:344:13)
    at Liftoff.execute (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:201:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:51:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:191:5)
    at C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:149:9
    at C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:138:14
    at C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:41:14
    at C:\Users\Xxx\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:53:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

  knex:query select * from `transactions` trx2 +185ms
  knex:bindings [] trx2 +227ms
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +201ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +88ms
  knex:bindings [ 7, 1 ] trx4 +73ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +158ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +137ms
  knex:bindings [ 1725, 0, 1 ] trx2 +109ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 1
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +35ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +33ms
  knex:bindings [ 2, 1 ] trx4 +33ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +2ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +3ms
  knex:bindings [ 195, 0, 2 ] trx2 +4ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 2
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +51ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +50ms
  knex:bindings [ 6, 1 ] trx4 +49ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +3ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +4ms
  knex:bindings [ 975, 0, 3 ] trx2 +4ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 3
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +36ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +35ms
  knex:bindings [ 5, 1 ] trx4 +35ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +10ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +31ms
  knex:bindings [ 650, 0, 4 ] trx2 +31ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 4
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +56ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +34ms
  knex:bindings [ 5, 1 ] trx4 +34ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +2ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +9ms
  knex:bindings [ 650, 0, 5 ] trx2 +31ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 5
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +62ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +55ms
  knex:bindings [ 6, 1 ] trx4 +34ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +4ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +6ms
  knex:bindings [ 975, 0, 6 ] trx2 +29ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 6
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +64ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +63ms
  knex:bindings [ 6, 1 ] trx4 +39ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +2ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +4ms
  knex:bindings [ 975, 0, 7 ] trx2 +34ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 7
  knex:client acquired connection from pool: __knexUid3 +66ms
  knex:query select `plans`.* from `plans` where `id` = ? limit ? trx4 +64ms
  knex:bindings [ 5, 1 ] trx4 +34ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid3 +3ms
  knex:query update `transactions` set `plan_price` = ?, `discount` = ? where `id` = ? trx2 +29ms
  knex:bindings [ 650, 0, 8 ] trx2 +30ms
  • Added original price and discount to transaction: 8
  knex:query insert into `migrations` (`batch`, `migration_time`, `name`) values (?, ?, ?) trx2 +36ms
  knex:bindings [ 4,
  knex:bindings   2020-01-09T21:13:03.923Z,
  knex:bindings   '20200105152452_add_plan_price_and_discount_to_transactions.js' ] trx2 +35ms
  knex:query update `migrations_lock` set `is_locked` = ? trx2 +24ms
  knex:bindings [ 0 ] trx2 +37ms
  knex:query COMMIT; trx2 +42ms
  knex:bindings undefined trx2 +44ms
  knex:tx trx2: releasing connection +945ms
  knex:client releasing connection to pool: __knexUid1 +146ms
Batch 4 run: 1 migrations
```

`knex -V` returns: "Knex CLI version: 0.20.2" and "Knex Local version: 0.20.3".

The full migration file looks as follows:

```
const Coupon = require('../../models/coupon');
const Plan = require('../../models/plan');

exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema
  .table('transactions', table => {
    table.decimal('plan_price', 10, 2);
    table.decimal('discount', 10, 2).defaultTo(0);
  })
  .then(() => {
    return knex('transactions').then(async transactions => {
      for (let trans of transactions) {
          let original_price;
          let total_coupon_discount = 0;

          const plan = await Plan.where({id: trans.plan_id}).fetch();
          if (plan) {
            original_price = plan.get("price");
          } else {
            original_price = null;
          }

          if (trans.coupon_id) {
            const coupon = await Coupon.where({id: trans.coupon_id}).fetch();
            if (coupon) {
              const amount_ex_vat = trans.amount_ex_vat;
              const couponAmount = coupon.get("discount_amount");
              let couponPercentage = 1;
              if ( coupon.get("discount_percentage") > 0 ) {
                couponPercentage = 1.0 / ( (100.0 - coupon.get("discount_percentage")) / 100.0 );
              }
              original_price = (amount_ex_vat * couponPercentage) + couponAmount;
              total_coupon_discount = original_price - amount_ex_vat;
            }
          }

          await knex("transactions")
            .where('id', '=', trans.id)
            .update({
              plan_price: original_price,
              discount: total_coupon_discount
            }).catch(function(error){
              console.log(error)
            }).then(function(){
              console.log('  • Added original price and discount to transaction: ' + trans.id);
            })
      }
    });
  });

exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.table('transactions', (table) => {
    table.dropColumn('plan_price');
    table.dropColumn('discount');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knex no longer takes the second `Promise` parameter, as it shifted to using native promises awhile back. `Promise` is therefore `undefined` in your migration, so there's definitely no `.resolve` property.

It's decidedly odd that someone thought returning `Promise.resolve().then` was a good idea anyway. What you want is to execute the schema modification, then the data modification. That will look something like this:

```
return knex.schema.table("transactions", t => {
  t.decimal('plan_price', 10, 2);
  // etc
})
  .then(() =>
    knex("transactions")
      .then(
        // Update values here
      );
  )
  .catch(console.error)
```

Further, what you are discovering is that `for_each` isn't always a terribly good fit for async
work. However, we can still make this migration work either by writing a more complex query (joining
the other tables to get the values we're after) or by modifying the current one to work better with
promises:

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema
    .table("transactions", t => {
      t.decimal("plan_price", 10, 2);
      t.decimal("discount", 10, 2).defaultTo(0);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return knex("transactions").then(async transactions => {
        for (let trans of transactions) {
          let original_price;
          let total_coupon_discount = 0;

          const plan = await Plan.where({ id: trans.plan_id }).fetch();
          if (plan) {
            original_price = plan.get("price");
          }

          if (trans.coupon_id) {
            const coupon = await Coupon.where({ id: trans.coupon_id }).fetch();
            if (coupon) {
              total_coupon_discount = coupon.get("discount_amount");
              original_price = trans.amount_ex_vat + couponAmount;
            }
          }

          await knex("transactions")
            .where("id", "=", trans.id)
            .update({
              plan_price: original_price,
              discount: total_coupon_discount
            });
        }
      });
    });
```

I obviously can't speak to the correctness of your other code (looks to me like Bookshelf?) because
I don't have your schema, but this is the general idea. Basically, when you want to use
`async`/`await` you go with `for... of`, keeping everything nice and sequential.

I think it's worth noting that this approach could be rather slow on a large table, with three
separate blocking queries per row of `transactions`.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the `Promise` and added an update to the OP with the errors that it now produces.

Comment: @Nick I've updated my answer to address your edits.

Comment: Thanks a million! The migration worked although I do still get the error: `Can't take lock to run migrations: Migration table is already locked. If you are sure migrations are not running you can release the lock manually by deleting all the rows = require(migrations lock table: migrations_lock
Unhandled rejection MigrationLocked: Migration table is already locked`
 
I even deleted all records from the `migrations_lock` table (local machine, so no risk) and the error was still there. If you think it is related to the migration file syntax, I would love to hear what might be causing it.

Comment: My guess is, this is related to previous failures to migrate. It definitely doesn't happen with a quick test on a couple of lines using the above structure (simplified, as I don't have your schema). It's worth noting that the table in question is `knex_migrations_lock`, not `migrations_lock`: perhaps there are still rows in that table?

Comment: I think I read that with the latest knex version the table is called `migrations_lock`. I don’t have any table with the word “knex” in it. I found a related issue and tried to follow the instructions there. They do seem to suggest there (https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1217#issuecomment-263824077), it could have to do with the syntax of the migration file. I have added info under “update2” to the OP.

Comment: I don't see anything in the changelog about it. Just as an experiment, I tried recreating a database with the latest version and definitely ended up with a `knex_migrations_lock` table. There is an option to set the name in your knexfile, so possibly you're doing it there? Regardless, try nuking the whole table `DROP TABLE migrations_lock;` as the next migration will simply recreate it, and see if that gets you anywhere!

Comment: Failing that, reproduce the exact migration you're using that results in this error in your question, and I'll take another look.

Comment: Thanks, dropping the table made no difference. I've added the full migrations file at the end of the OP. 
P.S. I think you're right about the table name, in `knexfile.js` I have the line `tableName: 'migrations'` that probably gives it the name `migrations_lock`.

Comment: Yep, you actually get two tables out of that name: `migrations` and `migrations_lock`, so that explains that. I'll look at the migration.

Comment: I just noticed your post says the log is from a rollback. Could you please run the migration (not the rollback) and post the log from that?

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced the rollback log with the log I get from the migration.

Comment: It almost looks... like it's running twice? How are you invoking this migration, from the command line? In code? Anything unusual in your knexfile? :)

Comment: I do have a script I run for migrations. But I also have over 20 previous migration files that do not return this error when using the same script. Just to be sure, I now also tried it by running `knex migrate:latest` instead of the script, and it indeed still returns the same error.

Comment: How frustrating for you! Um, I'm not sure what else to suggest. I'm wondering if perhaps this is a side effect of using Bookshelf during the migration. I'll post up a suggestion to try using pure Knex, it's worth a try to rule it out at least.

Comment: No problem, Rich. Thanks for your help. Most importantly, the migration does work even though it also returns an error.

Comment: I took a look at trying to do it with a join-and-update, but the math doesn't really work well and it's a bunch of `knex.raw`.